# Group Theoretical Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a function which assign to each group $G$ a subgroup $\alpha(G)$ such that

$(\alpha(G))^\theta=\alpha(G^\theta)$

for each homomorphism $\theta: G\rightarrow H$. Can we prove that if $X\leq Y$ are groups, then $\alpha(X)\leq \alpha(Y)$? If we can prove it, then $\alpha$ would be a functor I think (this is the real problem that I want to solve) - the image of a homomorphism $G\rightarrow H$ under $\alpha$ is understood to be its restriction to $\alpha(G)$.
Any hints?

Comment: I deleted my attempted answer as it was not correct and I do not see any way to fix it.

Comment: I think putting $\alpha(G)$ to be the intersection of the kernels of all surjective homomorphisms from $G$ to $A_5$ might be counterexample, but I need to think about it some more!

Comment: So you require that $\theta(\alpha(G)) = \alpha(\theta(G))$ for every endomorphism $\theta$ of $G$? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to require this for every homomorphism $G \to H$? Where does this problem appear?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I mean precisely this: for every homomorphism $G\rightarrow H$. I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: I think my idea of $\alpha(G)$ being intersection of kernels of epimorphisms $G \to A_5$ satisfies $\alpha(G)^\theta = \alpha(G^\theta)$ for finite groups $G$, but not always for infinite groups.

Comment: Let $W$ be a set of word in variables $x_1,..$ (a subset of the free group of countable rank).  Define $W(G)$ to be the subgroup generated by all values of words in $W$ on $G$.

It is not hard to show that $\alpha(G)=W(G)$, where $W=\alpha(F)$ and $F$ is the free group of countable rank. Then my statment is true. What do you think?